# React use hook inside eventListener

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-hooks, html5-audio

I have created the following hook to play audio in react:

```
"use client";

import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export const 

useAudio = (url: string) => {
  const [audio, setAudio] = useState<HTMLAudioElement | null>(null);
  const [playing, setPlaying] = useState(false);

  const setVolume = (volume: number) => {
    if (audio) audio.volume = volume;
    console.log(audio);
  };

  const toggle = () => {
    setPlaying(!playing);
    console.log(audio);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    playing ? audio?.play() : audio?.pause();
  }, [playing]);

  useEffect(() => {
    audio?.addEventListener("ended", () => audio?.play());
  }, [audio]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setAudio(new Audio(url));
    return () => {
      audio?.removeEventListener("ended", () => audio.play());
    };
  }, []);

  return { playing, toggle, setVolume };
};
```

When I console log the audio element inside the toggle function, I get the correct element, but in setVolume it is always null.

I set the volume in a eventListener mouseMove like this:

```
    document.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) {
      let element = document.getElementById("follow");
      let left = e.pageX;
      let top = e.pageY;
      element!.style.left = left + "px";
      element!.style.top = top + "px";

      const distance = Math.sqrt(
        Math.pow(left - devPosition.current.x, 2) +
          Math.pow(top - devPosition.current.y, 2)
      );

      setVolume(1 - distance / diagonal.current);
    });
```

Can this happen because I call setVolume inside such a listener? If so, what can I do about that?

Comment: You can't do `if (audio) audio.volume = volume;`, you'll need to use `setAudio`

Comment: roperty 'setVolume' does not exist on type 'HTMLAudioElement'.
According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/volume my way should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried your `useAudio` hook and I think that there is nothing wrong with the hook.

For example a component like this works as expected and doesn't yield any error.

```
"use client";

import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useAudio } from "./audioHook"

export default function Home() {
  const controls = useAudio('./horse.mp3');

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(controls.playing);
  }, [controls]);

  const workWithAudio = () => {
    controls.toggle();
  };

  const changeVolume = () => {
    controls.setVolume(0.2);
  };
  
  return (
    <main>
      <button onClick={workWithAudio}>
        The toggle button
      </button>
      <button onClick={changeVolume}>
        The volume button
      </button>
    </main>
  )
}
```

There could be issues in the way you handle the listener. If I understand correctly (for example look here [How to add a 'mousemove' event listener to a component Cursor which is moved with the cursor pointer in ReactJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58028788/how-to-add-a-mousemove-event-listener-to-a-component-cursor-which-is-moved-wit)) the preferred way to add a listener in a React component is by adding it to a DOM node, like this:

```
"use client";

import { useAudio } from "./audioHook"

export default function Home() {
  const controls = useAudio('./horse.mp3');

  const handleMouseMove = (e: MouseEvent) => {
    let element = document.getElementById("follow");
    let left = e.pageX;
    let top = e.pageY;
    element!.style.left = left + "px";
    element!.style.top = top + "px";

    // const distance = Math.sqrt(
    //   Math.pow(left - devPosition.current.x, 2) +
    //     Math.pow(top - devPosition.current.y, 2)
    // );

    controls.setVolume(0.5);
  }

  return (
    <main onMouseMove={handleMouseMove}>
      <div id="follow">TEST</div>
    </main>
  )
}
```

I don't have access to the `devPosition` and `diagonal` variables that you use in your function, so I had to use a constant, but if you instantiate the listener in this way you are able to set the volume without issues.

Comment: I got it to work by putting the listener inside the hook, ehich definitly isn't an ideal solution. I think this solutionis a lot cleaner and definitly the way to go